# Howto make local word assignment inside PARSE in REBOL?

Tags: parsing, rebol, rebol3

I need a function that uses `PARSE` and the `COPY x` rule, but does not change `x` outside the function. I tried to use `FUNCTION` to have it automatically pick up the local `x`, but it does not work:

```
>> f: function [t] [parse t [copy x to end]]
>> f ["a"]
== true
>> print x
a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your FUNCTION use, you're already halfway there. You can combine two recent changes:

1. [FUNCTION automatically gathers](http://www.rebol.com/article/0543.html) all set-word!s used in the body as local variables.
2. The COPY and SET rules of PARSE [have been relaxed](https://github.com/rebol/rebol/pull/165) to also accept set-word!s as their first argument.

So that'd give you:

```
;; Note the subtle change of `x` to `x:` compared to your original version:
>> f: function [t] [parse t [copy x: to end]]

>> f ["a"]
== true

>> x
** Script error: x has no value
```

Alternatively, you can also explicitly list your local variables using the `/local` convention:

```
>> f: function [t /local x] [parse t [copy x to end]]
>> f ["a"]
>> x
** Script error: x has no value
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, alternatively, you could use a set-word! **in** the function, but **outside** of parse.

```
>> f: function [t] [x: none c: charset [#"a" -#"] parse t [copy x some c] print x]
>> f "a"
a
>> x
** Script error: x has no value
```

While this has more overhead than the other alternatives, it may be helpful in debugging, if used like this:

```
>> f: function [t] [x: 10101 c: charset [#"a" -#"z"] parse t [copy x some c] print x]
>> f ""
10101
```

This makes it obvious, that the rule did not catch anything.